# Do i have a responsibility to report users breaking the rules?

Tags: halacha, internet, lashon-hara-slander, stackexchange, dina-dmalchusa-dina

If I know that a certain user of a website is breaking the rules, can I just turn a blind eye, or must I report it? Also,

- Does it matter what kind of rule it is? (E.g. No swearing vs. age requirement)
- Does it matter if it's socially accepted in that community to turn a blind eye? (See, for example [Are moderators required to report users younger than 13?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236710/are-moderators-required-to-report-users-younger-than-13))
- Does it matter if the user is Jewish or not?

Comment: ולמלשינים על תהי תקוה

Comment: Are you affiliated with this Web site in any way?

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang If that would make a difference, it should be included in an answer.

Comment: @aniyodea see scimonster's user profile about me section.

Comment: FWIW, the [ToS](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/legal) don't say that a user under 13 can't use the site, but rather that "*No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information to or on Stack Exchange*" ...but IANAL, and I don't know if there's any info that I missed.

Comment: A user under 13 is not a problem for the user, but a problem for the site.  COPPA says that sites can only collect very limited information from pre-teens.  Site policies are written to forbid pre-teens because they want to collect more information about their users and don't want to discriminate. Therefore, a violation of site policy is a self-denial of the protections offered by COPPA.

Comment: I wonder if [tag:lifnei-iver] is a good tag here.

Comment: @YeZ, funny. It doesn't seem that he's consistent however. The title has it in lower case but in the question itself it's upper.

Comment: @AniYodea that was an edit done by another user.  Which Scimonster somehow missed.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked Rav Tzvi Berkowitz about using someone else's Costco card.

He said that it depends if the rules are attempted to be enforced or not. With costco where they check your card so you cannot use someone else's card even if you would get away with it, but BJ's where they don't check cards when you walk in and they have self check out, you can use someone else's. This is similar to how I have heard many times that you are allowed to go 65 in a 55 (including [Rav Chaim Pinchas Sheinberg](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/80/Q1/)).

Regarding reporting someone else for breaking the rules, as long as there is one opinion that says its ok, you have no right to report them since they have what to rely on.